# SELECT mysql with php json encode

Tags: php, mysql, json

Here My code now :

```html
$sql = "SELECT * FROM schedule_feednow WHERE IDMac = '".$_GET["IDMac"]."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$json_data = array();

while($rec = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
 $Subjson = array();
 $Subjson['IDMac'] = $rec['IDMac'];
 $Subjson['DATETIME'] = $rec['DATETIME'];
 $Subjson['Weight'] = $rec['Weight'];
 
 array_push($json_data,$Subjson);
 

}

echo json_encode ($json_data);
```

and Result :

```
[{"IDMac":"C-01","DATETIME":"12:05:19 AM on June 23, 2017","Weight":"50"},{"IDMac":"C-01","DATETIME":"12:05:55 AM on June 23, 2017","Weight":"50"},{"IDMac":"C-01","DATETIME":"02:02:20 PM on June 23, 2017","Weight":"50"}]
```

But I don't want this Result

I want this Result->

```
["Schedule":{"IDMac":"C-01","DATETIME":"12:05:19 AM on June 23, 2017","Weight":"50"},{"IDMac":"C-01","DATETIME":"12:05:55 AM on June 23, 2017","Weight":"50"},{"IDMac":"C-01","DATETIME":"02:02:20 PM on June 23, 2017","Weight":"50"}]
```

Please help me to generate code or train me.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put your current result into an array with key "Schedule":

```
echo json_encode(array('Schedule' => $json_data));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create another array and put your json data in that:

```
$newJsonData = ['Schedule' => $json_data];
echo json_encode ($newJsonData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
echo json_encode ($json_data);
```

with

```
$myResult = ['Schedule' => $json_data];
echo json_encode ($myResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
$sql = "SELECT * FROM schedule_feednow WHERE IDMac = '".$_GET["IDMac"]."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$json_data = array();

while($rec = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 $json_data[] = $rec;
}

echo json_encode ('Schedule' => $json_data);
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation for your example?